# Force a scope refresh from outside a controller

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I have a jQuery UI select list that I'm using in a very basic AngularJS app. When the list is opened and an item is selected, this change doesn't make it through to Angular, so the app doesn't respond to the change. If I remove the jQuery UI aspect of it and make it a regular select list, it's fine.  I figure there must be a way to make them play nicely, does anyone know how to do this?

**Example:**

HTML:

```
<div data-ng-app="appExample">
    <h1>Example 1</h1>
    <p>No jQuery UI</p>
    <div data-ng-controller="appCtrl1">
        <select id="exampleList1" data-ng-model="selectedOption">
            <option value="0">Option 0</option>
            <option value="1">Option 1</option>
            <option value="2">Option 2</option>
        </select>
        <span class="result">You selected Option {{ selectedOption }}</span>
    </div>
    <h1>Example 2</h1>
    <p>jQuery UI</p>
    <div data-ng-controller="appCtrl2">
        <select id="exampleList2" data-ng-model="selectedOption">
            <option value="0">Option 0</option>
            <option value="1">Option 1</option>
            <option value="2">Option 2</option>
        </select>
        <span class="result">You selected Option {{ selectedOption }}</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
appExample = angular.module('appExample', []);

appExample.controller('appCtrl1', function ($scope) {
    $scope.selectedOption = 0;
});

appExample.controller('appCtrl2', function ($scope) {
    $scope.selectedOption = 0;
});

$(function () {
    $("#exampleList2").selectmenu();
});
```

JSFiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/wtp1esyg/2/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add a simple directive to be a wrapper of jquery plugin, like this:

```
appExample.directive('selectMenu', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        require: 'ngModel',// require ngModel controller
        link: function(scope, element, attrs, ngModelCtrl) {
            $(element).selectmenu({
                //update ngModel on menu change event
                change: function( event, ui ) {
                    scope.$apply(function() {
                      ngModelCtrl.$setViewValue(element.val());
                    });
                }
            });
        }
    };
});
```

And then update the select element:

```
<select data-ng-model="selectedOption" data-select-menu>
```

Updated fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/t4deu/n6ckujj2/

This works well for a basic AngularJS app. But the better is to avoid jquery and stick with angular directives and modules.

Comment: I really like this approach - thank you very much.  Unfortunately owing to strict deadlines I'm stuck with jQuery UI for now, but I'm making a note to move to Angular UI when possible.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that the jquery plugin is actually not using the select at all - it makes it invisible and then creates a series of divs and spans that represent it, then binds events to that.

This is a very jQuery way of doing things, but is completely disconnected from angular.

My advice is to change your approach completely - instead of using jQuery components, use angular **directives**. There are libraries (angular-ui, for example), that have ported much of the jquery-ui functionality over to native angular, so don't re-invent the wheel.

Comment: Sorry, I understand _why_ it's not updating, what my question is asking is if there is a way to manually trigger an update?